# How to Use CKNotification？

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit, cksubscription

I want to be notified when the value changes on cloudkit

this is my code:

```
let now = Date()
    let timeInterval:TimeInterval = now.timeIntervalSince1970
    let timeStamp = Int(timeInterval)
let publicDB = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase
    let bookID = CKRecord.ID(recordName: "\(timeStamp)")
    let book = CKRecord(recordType: "Book", recordID: bookID)
```

Comment: You need to read the [CloudKit Quick Start Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/Introduction/Introduction.html). While the code is in Objective-C, the concepts and the APIs are the same in Swift.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the problem by asking regularly.

Comment: How can this be the solution of the problem ?